# My innerHTML is generating content from my arrays as literal text. I want the data inside the array to generate

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, innerhtml

With this code, my loop runs through my array and generates fine in the alert. But when I use innerHTML it produces a actual text and not the data. What am I doing wrong?

```
var myArray = [];

myArray[0] = {name:"John", value:"Doe"};
myArray[1] = {name:"Jane", value:"Dew"};
myArray[2] = {name:"James", value:"Dot"};
myArray[3] = {name:"Jack", value:"Dax"};

for (var i=0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
//alert(myArray[i].name + '/' + myArray[i].value);
}

function byId(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

byId("full").innerHTML = "myArray[i].name + '/' + myArray[i].value;";
```

Comment: Tip: syntax highlighting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do:

```
.innerHTML = myArray[i].name + '/' + myArray[i].value;
```

Your code didn't work because you were outputing your js code as a string due to the double quotes.

If you want to show all the item values in the div, you'd have to do something like:

```
var text = [], 
for (var i=0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
   text.push( myArray[i].name + '/' + myArray[i].value);
}
byId("full").innerHTML = text.join('<br/>');
```

Cheers